# Magento 2: Get Product Collection With Multiple SKUs Filter

Tags: magento2, product, php, collection

I'm trying to get product collection with multiple skus filter, don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','sku']);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['in' => ['IS-OB-2165','TM-VIVO-Y15']]);
    $collection->setPageSize(3);

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        print_r($product->getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection ->addFieldToSelect('*'); // only need sku, price, id,
$collection ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['in' => array('IS-OB-2165','TM-VIVO-Y15')]);
```